# Using Nutch solrindex to index to multiple cores?

Tags: solr, nutch

Is there parameter in the `bin/nutch solrindex` command to indicate which Solr core to index to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of any core parameter. You should just include the name of the core in your [solr url](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20solrindex) parameter like this: `http://localhost:8983/solr/core0`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now.

Comment: This definitely works, don't be put off by the fact that you see a 404 when you access http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name, this is the way to choose a specific Solr core for your Apache Nutch spider...thanks

Comment: just add /admin to it to avoid getting 404. Nutch will use the select and update request handlers, adding their path to the configured solr core url.

Comment: Worked for me. I initially used host:8983/solr/#/core_name, but redirected me to index.html and failed with 405 method not supported.

Answer (score 0):

In nutch 1.4, this is what I use to index to different cores:

bin/nutch crawl urls/url1 -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/core1 -depth 10 -topN 10000